# How to count a record multiple times based on years of subscription

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a report that counts the number of subscriptions per year along with the avg revenue. The problem is when a customer orders a multi-year subscription they are wanting to count that customer for each year that they are active. So if the subscription starts in 2020 and expires in 2023 I need to count for 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023. The report needs to display by pub, count of customers, year, sales and avg sales. I am unsure how to get it to count the record multiple times and actually display the date for the proper year. For example if they started in 2020 and expire in 2023. I want the first count for the customer to show 2020 and the second count to show 2021 and so on.

```
select  top 6 count(distinct CTM_NBR) as 'Count',
dtl.PUB_CDE AS 'Pub',

SUM(tot_liab) as 'Sales',
YEAR(strt_DTE) as 'Start Year',
year(exp_dte) as 'exp_year',

case term
when '6' then '1 year'
when '12' then '2 years'
when '18' then '3 years'
when '24' then '4 years'
when '30' then '5 years'
when '36' then '6 years'
when '42' then '7 years'
when '48' then '8 years'
when '54' then '9 years'
when '60' then '10 years' else ' ' end as 'Years Subscribed'
from CIRSUB_M  dtl
where YEAR(STRT_DTE) >= '2013' 

and dtl.PUB_CDE in ('MEN')--('FCM','GEM','GRT','MEN','FER','HGR','MCC') 
and CRC_STS in ('r','w','p') and TERM > 6 and year(CTG_DTE) > '2012'
and CTM_NBR not in (select ord.CTM_NBR from PROOLN_M oln
                    inner join PROORD_M ord on ord.ORD_NUM = oln.ORD_NUM
                    and YEAR(ord.CTG_DTE) = YEAR(dtl.CTG_DTE)
                    and SUBSTRING(oln.PMO_CDE,2,2) = 'ME'
                    and oln.ITM_NUM <> 'DIGITAL SUB')
group by YEAR(strt_DTE),dtl.CTG_DTE,EXP_DTE, TERM, dtl.PUB_CDE
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q9gL.png)

Comment: Can you share the colums in `CIRSUB_M` table? Do you have `start_date` and `end_date` or `start_date` and `subscription_duration`?

Comment: Yes there is a start date and and end date in CIRSUB_M. I can share the fields but it is really really lengthy.

Comment: Table definitions and sample data would help considerably here.

Comment: Is there a way to attach a file as it is too long to just paste?

Comment: You don't need to share anything that is not useful to solving your problem. In your query there are only a handful of columns you directly reference - only need sample data of those columns.

Comment: The answer from a [past question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510573/sql-server-2008-multiple-orders-for-the-same-customer-split-dupes-into-a-sepa) is a good starting point it seems. That answer is a good example of how to post useful, consumable information.

Comment: I have added some sample data.

Comment: No - you added an image. That image does not match the schema implied by your code. As already noted, posting an actual script will encourage others to help you.

Comment: I have updated the code so that it matches the image.